# Parameter has no default value , database c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to add information to my database. I have this code

```
private OleDbConnection connect;
private OleDbCommand command;

public DataBaseManager()
{
        connect = new OleDbConnection();
        command = new OleDbCommand();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Aurelian\Desktop\Photo.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        connect.Open();
        command.Connection = connect;
}

public void AddAlbum (Album newAlbum)
{
   command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Album VALUES(@Id,@Name,@Description,@Location,@Data)";// + Int32.Parse(newAlbum.ID.ToString()) + ",'" + newAlbum.Name.ToString() + "','" + newAlbum.Description.ToString() + "','" + newAlbum.Location.ToString() + "'," + Convert.ToDateTime(newAlbum.Date.ToString()) + ")";

   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", newAlbum.ID);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", newAlbum.Name);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", newAlbum.Description);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", newAlbum.Location);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", newAlbum.Date);

   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and the call:

```
DataBaseManager dm = new DataBaseManager();
Album alb=new Album(5,"TEST","TestDescriere","TestLocatie",new DateTime(2012,12,12));
dm.AddAlbum(alb);
```

The problem is on this line:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and this is the error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Parameter @Name has no default value.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint at line  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", newAlbum.Name); can you see the Name value?

Comment: If you break at the line that adds the @Name parameter, does it have a value?

Comment: Can you also show the class constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check you are actually setting the name property in your class constructor.

Comment: I disagree because it could be a solution.

Comment: not from me :), i give you upvote :D, was just my foult, i forgot to set name in constructor

Comment: Please mark my answer as the answer then :) All the best.

Comment: So newAlbum.Name was null then?

Comment: lol though I don't know who downvoted you, but let me upvote you since you've answered correctly.

Comment: Thrown one your way too Zach :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your newAlbum.Name is null.

Comment: but the name is TEST
`Album alb=new Album(5,"TEST","TestDescriere","TestLocatie",new DateTime(2012,12,12));`

Comment: Can we see the constructor for Album? Perhaps you are setting another property with "TEST", instead of the Name property you think it's setting

Comment: @user3052078 and does that constructor actually work?

Comment: Good job!  Whoever down-voted my answer please explain.